# Custom buy now button in shopify

Tags: shopify

How to create a custom buy now button in Shopify without the payment gateway. It should be redirected to the checkout page.

[image]

```
        {{ form | payment_button }}
```

above one is a dynamic button. But don't want to redirect to the payment gateway. It should redirect to checkout.

And I tried the below code. Which is not good. It shows also a popup for add to cart and redirects.

```html
  <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants" id="product-actions-{{ product.id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="variantId" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" />
<button class="button buynow-btn" title="Buy" onClick="instantBuy()"><span>Buy now</span></button>
</form>
```

```
 function instantBuy(){
     var $ = jQuery;
   $(".engo-popup").hide();

   var formParams = $('form.cart').serialize();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/cart/add",
      type: "post",
      data: formParams,
      success: function(){
       window.location.href = "/checkout";
      },
      error: function(){
      }
     })
    }
```

Comment: These dynamic buy now buttons generated by Shopify according to your payment gateways. you can't replicate by own, you need to use AJAX to add to the cart and then redirect to the checkout page using code.

Comment: How to create like that. when I created like this it shows a popup

Comment: Popup might be used by the theme code, you need to check and enhance the flow of theme code to work it according to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was inside the form. That's why it shows a popup

```js
  
 function instantBuy(){
     var $ = jQuery;

   var formParams = $('form.cart').serialize();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/cart/add",
      type: "post",
      data: formParams,
      success: function(){ 
       window.location.href = "/checkout";
      },
      error: function(){
      }
     })
 }
```

```html
 {% endform %}
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants" id="product-actions-{{ product.id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="variantId" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" />
<button class="button buynow-btn" title="Buy" onClick="instantBuy()"><span>Buy now</span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Also quantity input can be added

Answer (score 2):

This method adds product to cart & redirects to checkout page.

```
 addCartCheckout(el) {

    let form = document.querySelector('form[action="/cart/add"]');
    let formData = new FormData(form);

    fetch('/cart/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            location.href='/checkout';
            return response.json();
        }
        throw response;
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is to create a url link with **variant id** & **total quantity** & redirect to checkout Page onclick.
Example:

- `https://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/cart/36485954240671:3` -- checkout with one variant
- `https://my-shop-name.myshopify.com/cart/36485954240671:3,31384149360662:1` -- Add multiple variant

  ```
  //Select form --------------
  let form = document.querySelector('form[action="/cart/add"]');

  //Onclick Buynow -----------
  let btnBuy = form.querySelector('#buyNow');
  btnBuy.onclick = e => {

   //Get Variand Id -----------
   let variantId = form.querySelector('input[name="id"]').getAttribute('value')

   //Get Total Item -----------
   let quantity = form.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]').value; 

   //Generate link & redirect -----------
   let host = window.location.hostname;
   let newurl = `//${host}/cart/${variantId}:${quantity}`
   window.location.href = newurl;
  }
  ```